# Compiling Typescript to use as a JSFL script

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, adobe, jsfl

So at my job I need to write a lot JSFL scripts.  And because of the way JSFL, the scripts tend to be gigantic files, with functions and spaghetti everywhere.

So I had an idea to write them in Typescript, using separate files as "modules" (like I'm used to for commonjs/es6).  And compile that all down to a single file.

I've tried searching but I've been unable to come up with an answer.  Since JSFL just expects a simple javascript file.  I obviously can't use commonjs, amd, etc.

So is there a way, that when developing. I can write separate "modules", have typescript (or if needed webpack) compile them into a single javascript file?  Just like copy the functions from each file, and place it into one big file.

I'm not sure if its possible with typescript, or if I'll have to use some script or something to extract all the functions out.

Also since Adobe's JSFL is using an ancient javascript engine, it doesn't support a lot of features, and I will be adding polyfills to fill those holes.

Comment: Did it work out for you? Are there some type definitions for the APIs somewhere?

Comment: I did get it working using webpack and a whole lot of polyfills.  I even wrote some "components" that could be reused.  However I left that job for something better, and no longer have access to the source.  I can try to go through my backups and see if I can find an early version or something.

Comment: Thx for the information, but no further effort required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the typescript compiler option `--outfile`

> Concatenate and emit output to single file. The order of concatenation
>   is determined by the list of files passed to the compiler on the
>   command line along with triple-slash references and imports. See
>   output file order documentation for more details.

See also [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).